# Outlook2007 reminders not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007, reminder

I have outlook 2007 sp2 and the reminders have all of a sudden stopped flashing up when there due i have checked the settings and there enabled i have restarted my pc to see if that clearded anything but this hasnt worked. any suggestions on how to get this to work again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several possible solutions, so let's try from the easiest ones and work our way up :-)

[1] Click on File -> Options -> Advanced
In 'Reminders' section check to see if 'Show reminders' is checked.

[2] Start Outlook with '/cleanreminders' command
(Start -> Run -> outlook /cleanreminders)

[3] Start Outlook with '/cleanfreebusy' command
(Start -> Run -> outlook /cleanfreebusy)

If none of this helps you out, let me know.
There are other things we can try, but you may not like them.

Edit:
[4] A corrupted reminder
Now you'll see why this may be the solution you will like if you have many of them :-(
Open Calendar, click on View -> Current View -> Recurring appointments.
Opened each one of them until you get the error "Recurrence data not found".
Delete this one and you should be all good to go.

Edit 2:
[5] Corrupted cache
Are you using Exchange? If so, disable the cached mode and restart Outlook. This will clear the corrupted cache .ost file. Enable cached mode again and restart once more. Outlook will rebuild your cache files from scratch.

[6] Multiple data files
Is it possible that you created more than one data file? Check this by going to Tools -> Options -> Mail setup -> Data Files. It there is another one in addition to your default data file, it's most likely causing this. Oh, and before deleting the not-needed one - Backup! I can not stress this enough.

[7] Outlook with POP3 mailbox
If you are not using Exchange, Outlook will keep all of your reminders in .pst file, as there will be no .ost cache. That may mean the main .pst file is corrupted. Unfortunately, a step-by-step guide will take quite a while for me to write down here, so let's please make sure that you are in fact using POP3 and steps 5 and 6 failed.

[8] If changed from cached exchange mode - check outlook - options - calendar options - delete offline items

Comment: step 1 the box is checked step 2 didnt work Step 3 Didnt work. Thanks for trying

Comment: @ben950, don't worry, we'll get to the bottom of this. I edited the answer, please try step 4 :-)

Comment: Step 4 i have gone through didnt have an many as i thought but that didnt show up any errors

Comment: @ben950, sorry to hear it didn't work. I added some new possible solutions I could think of. Hope one of them will help.

Comment: Thankyou Step 5 worked =) must of been corrupt cache. Thanks one again

Comment: Yaaay! I'm so glad it worked! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a little reminders thing at the bottom of outlook?

[image]

Double click that to bring it up and then handle the reminders and again they'll pop up when they're due. This happens because the reminder popped up but was minimized and the pop up window was closed without it being snoozed or dismissed. Outlook then decides you want to aggregate this action with future reminders.

Comment: It isnt displaying reminders like that it is really odd was working 2 days ago then just stopped. Is there a maximun ammount of remiders you can have as i might of exceded that number

Comment: @Raystafarian, +1 for answer. It's quite possible. ben950, there is no maximum number of reminders you can have. Or at least you'll never hit the maximum even if you try :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change it from a cached Exchange mode, check Outlook:

> options -> calendar options -> delete offline items

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted reminders after I fixed a sync problem with Exchange ActiveSync for Android were the problem. I had to methodically move them out of my mail and task folders to a temporary location, then open them in batches until I found and repaired the problem tasks, then move them back to their original location.

Time-consuming, but everything is working again.